# mod_jk.log shows what url?

Tags: apache, tomcat, security, mod-jk

I have mod_jk connector between Apache and Tomcat (on Ubuntu) and I'm looking at the mod_jk.log. The log mainly looks like this:

```
[Fri Jan 18 18:37:32 2013]ajp13 <some url from my domain> 0.011095
```

But occasionally I see these entries:

```
[Fri Jan 18 21:09:58 2013]ajp13 www.bradesco.com.br 0.030327
[Fri Jan 18 21:09:58 2013]ajp13 www.bb.com.br 0.009310
[Fri Jan 18 21:09:58 2013]ajp13 www.santander.com.br 0.011401
[Fri Jan 18 21:09:58 2013]ajp13 www.banese.com.br 0.010602
```

Does anybody know what urls are logged in mod_jk.log? Are these "br" entry legitimate?

Thanks.

Comment: This link may help you   http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/reference/printer/apache.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I changed mod_jk log level to debug - we'll see. The strange thing is why some random Brazilian bank pings some unknown host which is not even in production. Does it have its own web spider?

Comment: Or maybe it's the other way around - somebody tries to DDOS Brazilian bank using my server as a relay. Yes, I'm paranoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is not specific to mod_jk in any way, it just was initially observed in mod_jk logs.

All Brazilian URLs are coming from `Host` header property of the `GET` request. And as suggested in this [comment](http://forum.linode.com/viewtopic.php?p=53710&sid=f53f67f3c9e06332b38fcc6fc3eb5f05) this is a scan for open proxies.

Interesting enough it comes from the same IP address (65.111.177.188) for many months.

To shut this garbage out I added an extra rule to the mod_security conf file on the server:

```
SecRule &REQUEST_HEADERS:Host "!@pm mydomain" "phase:1,deny"
```

so that all hosts without `mydomain` in them are denied right away.